# Changing logging level at runtime in ktor application

Tags: kotlin, logging, ktor

Previously I worked with Spring Boot and I could change logging level for concrete class without app restart due to Spring Boot actuator (just http request on loggers endpoint). 
Now I'm working with ktor and I also want to change logging level at runtime.
How can I do that?